# Why does Node think this isn't a function but javascript is fine sometimes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, aws-lambda

I have a larger project I'm working on that's calling a Lambda in AWS via an API Gateway that I've configured. In the Lambda I'm trying to dynamically call a variable based on a query string param on an API request by using the following:

```
var functionToCall = event.queryStringParameters.tech;
console.log("functionToCall is " + functionToCall);
global[functionToCall](event, output);
```

Unfortunately I get an error of

```
TypeError: global[functionToCall] is not a function
```

I've rewritten this using window to demonstrate it online and depending on whether I run it in jsbin or jsfiddle I get different results. The following works in jsbin:

```
'use strict';
var functionArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
var randFunction = functionArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * functionArray.length)];

function one() {
  console.log("function one called");
};

function two() {
  console.log("function two called");
};

function three() {
  console.log("function three called");
};

console.log(randFunction);
window[randFunction]();
```

When I run it in jsfiddle I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: window[randFunction] is not a function
    at window.onload (VM99:49)
```

Ultimately I'm looking for some help in running this in my Lambda(node.js) as it'll make things easier and also help me be DRY.

Thanks!

Comment: jsFiddle wraps code in a function, therefore variables are not global.

Comment: @FelixKling That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Node.js, each module has its own scope, and you never get implicit globals.

Instead of relying on strings and globals, you should make an array of functions directly:

```
var functions = [
  function() {...},
  function() {...},
  function() {...}
];
```

Comment: Could you expand a little further and provide an example please?

Comment: Thanks! Could I utilize an array of function requests so that I can have my code for each elsewhere? If not how would your array look with named functions? Also, would I be able to reference them via `functions[event.queryStringParameters.tech]` ?

Comment: Yes; you can make an array of anything you want.  If you want to reference by name instead of by index, use an object.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks! I've run into an issue where having `var functions = { "foo": foo(event, output), "bar": bar(event, output) };` actually calls the functions instead of just creating the object for me to call later.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @metropolis: You're calling the functions.  If you want to pass a function, you need to pass a function expression that calls the functions.

Comment: @SLaks: Oh duh. :facepalm: Thanks!